# 3x2 within subjects design with covariate that is nested within factor (?)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, repeated-measures, ancova, nested-data

I want to test the differences in my interval-scaled dependent variable - measured at three time intervals (within subj.), for two conditions (within subj.), while accounting for a interval-scaled covariate that has two values per subject (one per condition).

Sample size is low twenties. Data looks like this:

[image]
What's the best way to go about testing this?

To my understanding, a typical repeated measures ANOVA struggles with this because the covariate has different values for the same person depending on the second within subject factor. I was wondering if a mixed model could accommodate the design, but my knowledge of lme4 is too limited.

Could someone share an insight?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this situation could be modeled with a mixed effects model, with crossed random effects (random intercepts) for `Subject` and `Condition`:

```
Outcome ~ Time + Covariate + (1| Subject) + (1|Condition)
```

However, since there appears to be a 1:1 correspondence between `Covariate` and `Condition` and your research question seems to be about the fixed effect of `Covariate` the  random effect for `Condition` may not be needed (including it may not change the estimate for `Covariate` but it may reduce the precision of it).

Comment: Thank you for this helpful comment.

However, I am also interested in the Fixed Effect of Condition. Could I just add it as an additional factor like this, or would this neglect the nesting of the covariate?

Outcome ~ Time + Covariate + Condition + (1| Subject)

Comment: Is there a 1:1 correspondence between `Covariate` and `Condition` which is implied by your sample data and your question where it says *" (one per condition)"*. If so, that will result in a rank-deficient fixed effects model matrix, so you would have to just include  `Condition` as a fixed effect.

Comment: Just to clarify, if `Covariate` and `Condition` are perfectly correlated, you can't include both of them as fixed effects (you can still include `Time`